# Issue with implementing Adwhirl

Tags: iphone, ios, adwhirl

I am implementing ad-whirl in my iOS project. I need advertisement in my app by 3 networks, Admob, Millennial Media and iAd. I already activated those 3 networks on my ad-whirl account and I downloaded the example SDK for Adwhirl. But the Adnetworkslib folder is empty - how can I add those networks lib to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download those SDK's separately, they do not come packaged with AdWhirl. You can download Millennial from [here](http://mmedia.com/?refsite=developer#developerHome), and AdMob from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download).

I believe iAd is just a linked framework that you add to your project in XCode.